# Web App using HTML Service and Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a script that I can deploy as a web app.  I have a spreadsheet with names of teachers signed up for different professional development sessions.

I need to be able to select the session from a drop down list of all the sessions, then take attendance using checkboxes.  Each session will have different teachers attending, so the attendance roster needs to be dynamic.

I am SO very new to `GAS` that I hate asking for such basic help. I'm about 3 weeks into `GAS` and 3 days into web app and HTML service.

I then want to write a "1" back to the spreadsheet if they attended.  (I figured this part out so far).

Any help would be wonderful.

Here is the `code.gs`

```
function doGet() {
    return HtmlService
        .createTemplateFromFile('Index')
        .evaluate();
}
```

Here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <base target="_top">
    </head>
    <body>
    <? var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1ZDV68w82btNbg1Or63u97i8wn7pXyV2gZUfwXlqwUJI').getSheetByName('sheet1'); ?>
    <? var data = sheet
        .getDataRange()
        .getValues(); ?>
        <? for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
            <? if (data[i][0] == "Session 1"){ ?>
                <? sheet.getRange(i+1, 3).setValue("1"); ?>
            <? } ?>
        <? } ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Not much here yet -- I don't understand creating buttons or handling responses.  Nor producing output directly from responses.  I have done a ton of research in the past few days to try and pull some examples, but there are very few out there.

Comment: What have you tried so far though? What first steps have you taken? Where has your research led you?

Comment: I updated my question with what little I have so far.  Still tons of work to do, but haven't stopped researching.

Comment: Have you read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web?

Comment: too broad and no specific coding issue.